# Which design pattern to use to keep things DRY while offering Decoration?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, decorator, dry

As I dive more into the core of frameworks, I wanted to do a reality check and make sure some of my approaches to composition and dependency injection are still well balanced. Situations that seem to keep popping up are those in which I need to improve the DRYness of a class and give room for future decoration, all the while ensuring tricky encapsulation doesn't go overboard and make it really challenging to follow the code. Of course there will be supporting documentation, but we all want the code to in many ways just "speak to us". So here's a simple scenario...

Imagine there are many classes like the one below. Dave's Car, Tom's Car, Susan's Car, etc...etc...etc....etc...

```
class DaveCar {
    public $labor;

    public function getLabor($userInput)
    {
         $this->labor = ... // Logic same for ALL cars
    }

    public function wheels()
    {
         $this->labor += ...    // Logic unique to Dave's Car
         return ...            
    }

    public function body()
    {
         $this->labor *= ...    // Logic unique to Dave's Car 
         return ... 
    }

    public function build()
    {
         // Logic here is same for ALL cars
         return $this->wheels() + $this->body();
    }
}
```

Now suppose we create a class called `CarBuilder` to store the repetitive logic, populate some of the properties of the car class, and also act as a decorator. We could reduce our car classes to only those unique functions:

```
class DaveCar implements CarBuilderInterface{
    public $labor;

    public function wheels()
    {
         $this->labor += ...    // Logic unique to Dave's Car
         return ...            
    }

    public function body()
    {
         $this->labor *= ...    // Logic unique to Dave's Car 
         return ... 
    }
}
```

And call it like this (Note: I'm using Facades, not singletons here):

```
$cheapCar   = CarBuilder::(new DaveCar)->getLabor(1)->build();
$qualityCar = CarBuilder::(new DaveCar)->getLabor(5)->build();
```

In the real world (wide web), later on I may add more decoration such as `->buildJSON` or `->buildPDF` and so on.

Here are the questions I have that will clarify my thinking is on the right track:

1. Is it good I avoided inheritance here? (adhering to "Composition over Inheritance" without becoming "Compose-always")
2. What design pattern did I use here?
3. What design pattern SHOULD I have used here?
4. Did I hide too much logic?
5. How do I ensure other developers will know that `CarBuilder` requires the property `public $labor` in their car classes? Interfaces will give the required methods, but do nothing about properties. Currently I just document in the interface file that this property is required (even though I can't enforce it code-wise from the interface).

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up things a little bit. The `CarBuilder` builds `Car`s. It is like a factory, but for more complex and more general cases... For example:

```
class CarBuilder {
    /** @var Car */
    protected $car;
    public function newCar(){
        $this->car = new Car();
    }

    public function addWheels(Wheel $wheel){
        $this->car->setWheel($wheel);
    }

    public function addWindow(Window $window, $position){
            if ($position == Car::FORWARD_WINDOW)
                $this->car->setForwardWindow($window);
    }

    ...

    /** @return Car */
    public function getCar(){
            return $this->car;
    }
}

class DaveCarFactory {
    public function createDaveCar(){
        $carBuilder = new CarBuilder();
        $carBuilder->newCar();
        $carBuilder->addWheels(new VerySpecialWheel());
        $carBuilder->addWindow(new UvFilteredWindow(), Car::FORWARD_WINDOW);
        ...
        $car = $carBuilder->getCar();
        return $car;
    }
}
```

Using the builder in a [train wreck anti pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TrainWreck) can be allowed in this special case (as long as objects hide inner data), and it is called [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) in other words:

```
class DaveCarFactory {
    public function createDaveCar(){
        return (new CarBuilder())
            ->newCar()
            ->addWheels(new VerySpecialWheel())
            ->addWindow(new UvFilteredWindow(), Car::FORWARD_WINDOW)
            ...
            ->getCar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok let me digest this tonight and get back to you tomorrow. +1 for train wreck vs. fluent interface. I'll give you my thoughts on chaining as well.